# Featured image overlay when changing post status

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, post-status

I have a car brokerage in Spain with wordpress website using the MOTORS theme from Themeforest. Out of the box, the theme didn´t have all the functionality I wanted, primarily the ability to mark cars as sold.

I´ve managed to add a custom post status, however, I was wondering whether I´d be able to add a "SOLD" badge overlay on the featured image when the post status is changed to sold.

The website in question is www.carsinspain.es

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Dan

Comment: Use the browser's inspector (F12) and look if there is a class being added for that post status, check the parent divs of the car.  If so you could use CSS to add an overlay image.